# why can i not get the injection to work?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a project and i am trying to inject my service, but i keep getting null pointer exception injecting the UserService. And i cannot figure out what i am missing.

I added the project to my github, https://github.com/JohnnyBekkestad/demo, mind you that in order to focus on the problem i removed a lot of code to clean it up.

If anyone can see what i am missing i would gratefully appreciate it.

Best Regards
Johnny

Comment: No chance to get an answer if you don't post your source code and point out the class/line where the error occurs.

Comment: Yes, at a minimum please post your stack trace.

Comment: NullPointer Exception in Line27 in the UserController.java

Answer (score 2):

Your `WAR` file is missing a `beans.xml` file here: https://github.com/JohnnyBekkestad/demo/tree/master/web/rest/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Assuming that you're trying to inject the service here and this is where the NPE Is coming from:

https://github.com/JohnnyBekkestad/demo/blob/master/web/rest/src/main/java/se/johnny/demo/web/rest/UserController.java

Comment: That is correct i am trying to inject in UserController.java, but it did not work when i added the beans.xml

Comment: Follow-up to this, since you're doing a multimodule project you'll need META-INF/beans.xml in addition to the beans.xml in the WEB-INF of the WAR.

Comment: @BeauJohnnyBekkestad please post your stack trace.  LightGuard that's definitely not required, though may depend on your app server.

Comment: added the stacktrace to github
https://github.com/JohnnyBekkestad/demo/blob/master/stacktrace.txt

observe that the code lines will be different since i have removed quite some code to make it more readable.
The problem is on Line27 of the UserController.java

Comment: Try annotating your REST class `@RequestScoped`, rather than `@ManagedBean`.  Also, what application server are you using (name and version).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.lucubratory.eu/getting-weld-cdi-into-tomcat-7/) if using Tomcat and remember to add beans.xml, to change web.xml and incluce / exclude the not necessary dependencies ([weld](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld)). Furthermore there is no such annotation pair

```
@Path 
@ManagedBean
```

Remember: JAX-RS (or in your case Jersey) tells you, when it finds any implementation, which means @Path is enough:

```
INFO: Root resource classes found:
   class com.bekkestad.demo.web.rest.UserController
```

And as a starter: Tomcat is no Java EE container. If using GlassFish 4 then get comfortable with Java EE first (@EJB > @Stateless) then add CDI capability - but then you do not have to add any dependencies since weld is already available (= no context.xml or changes in web.xml needed, just a beans.xml in WEB-INF and also in all other projects META-INF directories).